# make cron in odoo 11 for generate payroll batch

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-10, odoo-11

hi am trying to create cron for generate batch of payslip in odoo 11 this is my code

```
    def _cron_generate_batches_generate_payslips(self):
        payslip_employee_pool = self.env['hr.payslip.employees']
        today = datetime.today()
        start_date = datetime(today.year, today.month, 1)
        if today.month == 12:
            next_month = 1
            year = today.year + 1
        else:
            next_month = today.month + 1
            year = today.year
        next_month_start_day = datetime(year, next_month, 1)
        end_date = next_month_start_day - relativedelta(days=1)
        batch_name = 'Payslip Batch for ' + calendar.month_name[today.month] + ' - ' + str(today.year)
        payslip_batch_vals = {
            'date_start': start_date,
            'date_end': end_date,
            'name': batch_name
        }
        payslip_batch = self.create(payslip_batch_vals)
        employee_objs = self.env['hr.employee'].search([])
        employee_ids = []
        for employee in employee_objs:
            employee_ids.append(employee.id)
        ctx = dict(self.env.context) or {}
        ctx.update({
            'active_model': 'hr.payslip.run',
            'journal_id': payslip_batch.journal_id and payslip_batch.journal_id.id,
            'salary_rule_id': payslip_batch.salary_rule_id,
            'active_ids': [payslip_batch.id],
            'active_id': payslip_batch.id
        })
        payslip_employee_obj = payslip_employee_pool.with_context(ctx).create({'employee_ids': [(6, 0, employee_ids)]})
        payslip_employee_obj.compute_sheet()
```

and i change in this function for get the same structure for all payslip

```
  @api.multi
    def compute_sheet(self):
        payslips = self.env['hr.payslip']
        [data] = self.read()
        active_id = self.env.context.get('active_id')
        if active_id:
            [run_data] = self.env['hr.payslip.run'].browse(active_id).read(
                ['date_start', 'date_end', 'credit_note', 'salary_rule_id'])
        from_date = run_data.get('date_start')
        to_date = run_data.get('date_end')
        if not data['employee_ids']:
            raise UserError(_("You must select employee(s) to generate payslip(s)."))
        for employee in self.env['hr.employee'].browse(data['employee_ids']):
            slip_data = self.env['hr.payslip'].onchange_employee_id(from_date, to_date, employee.id,
                                                                    contract_id=False)
            import logging
            # logging.error(slip_data['value']['struct_id'])
            # struct = self.env['hr.payroll.structure'].search([('id', '=', slip_data['value']['struct_id'])], limit=1)
            logging.error( run_data.get('salary_rule_id'))
            logging.error( run_data.get('salary_rule_id')[0])

            res = {
                'employee_id': employee.id,
                'name': slip_data['value'].get('name'),
                'struct_id': run_data.get('salary_rule_id')[0],
                'contract_id': slip_data['value'].get('contract_id'),
                'payslip_run_id': active_id,
                'input_line_ids': [(0, 0, x) for x in slip_data['value'].get('input_line_ids')],
                'worked_days_line_ids': [(0, 0, x) for x in slip_data['value'].get('worked_days_line_ids')],
                'date_from': from_date,
                'date_to': to_date,
                'credit_note': run_data.get('credit_note'),
                'company_id': employee.company_id.id,
            }
            payslips += self.env['hr.payslip'].create(res)
        payslips.compute_sheet()
        #pdb.set_trace()
        return {'type': 'ir.actions.act_window_close'}
```

and this is the error that i got:

```
   File "c:\program files (x86)\odoo 11.0\server\odoo\addons_cetic\bt_hr_payroll_automatic\models\hr_payroll.py", line 50, in _cron_generate_batches_generate_payslips
    payslip_employee_obj.compute_sheet()
  File "c:\program files (x86)\odoo 11.0\server\odoo\addons_cetic\bt_hr_payroll_automatic\models\hr_payroll.py", line 102, in compute_sheet
    logging.error( run_data.get('salary_rule_id')[0])
ValueError: : "'bool' object is not subscriptable" while evaluating
'model._cron_generate_batches_generate_payslips()'
```

thanks for help

Comment: What doe's `run_data.get('salary_rule_id')` returns?

Comment: return the id of structure, i add in hr.payslip.run to get the same structure for all payslip

Comment: `salary_rule_id` is a many2one field and may return `False` when its value is not provided. You got that error because  `run_data.get('salary_rule_id')` returned a boolean value (`False`). Make sure it returns an integer value or False then remove `[0]`.